# Javascript form automatic calculation

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to create form which automatically alters a text box when the user uses keystrokes .

This fiddle illustrates what I am attempting however I have had no success.

Essentially I want the 3rd text box to show the "Number of People" multiplied by the "Price", how can I do this?

HTML

```
<form action="postenquiry.php" method="post" name="myform">
    <label>Num of People</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" />
    <br/>
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="Cost" onkeyup="calculate()" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="textbox5" />
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function calculate() {
    if (isNaN(document.forms["myform"]["qty"].value) || document.forms["myform"]["qty"].value == "") {
        var text1 = 0;
    } else {
        var text1 = parseInt(document.forms["myform"]["qty"].value);
    }
    if (isNaN(document.forms["myform"]["Cost"].value) || document.forms["myform"]["Cost"].value == "") {
        var text2 = 0;
    } else {
        var text2 = parseFloat(document.forms["myform"]["Cost"].value);
    }
    document.forms["myform"]["textbox5"].value = (text1 * text2);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b87s5hou/

Comment: You have to place the code in the head, not on load event: http://jsfiddle.net/b87s5hou/1/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown That's not true at all. As long as the code is added to the head or run through a onload/DOMContentLoaded event then it will work all the same.

Comment: @MikeC when user attach the event as he did `onkeyup="calculate()"` he attached a function in global escope, but when the function is declared inside the `onload` event, it is not global. In the `head` tag, outside any block it is global, therefore it can be called by the event.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown You're right. I so seldom place function calls directly on an element that I forgot this.

Comment: @MikeC np, this option in fiddle is very confusing...

Comment: jQuery solution with whole number constraint on people value:  http://jsfiddle.net/9qakb5ca/10/

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few errors in your code — take a look at the following to help you.

HTML

```
<form action="postenquiry.php" method="post" name="myform" onkeyup="calculate()">
    <label>Num of People</label>
    <input type="text" name="qty" />
    <br/>
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="text" name="cost" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="textbox5" />
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var form = document.forms.myform,
    qty = form.qty,
    cost = form.cost,
    output = form.textbox5;

window.calculate = function () {
    var q = parseInt(qty.value, 10) || 0,
        c = parseFloat(cost.value) || 0;
    output.value = (q * c).toFixed(2);
};
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/b87s5hou/7/)

Comment: These two lines could be shortened to `var text1 = parseInt(qty.value, 10) || 0; var text2 = parseFloat(cost.value) || 0;`.

Comment: Also, you could move `onkeyup="calculate()"` to the `<form>` instead of the `<input>` (so that changes from _both_ fields get applied immediately) and change the last line to `output.value = (q * c).toFixed(2);` (so that you never get a price of `2199.8900000000003`).

Comment: Why not post an answer or edit this one? I cleaned up some code quickly to help someone - get a grip man!

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned PHP but you can update these fields on the fly with just javascript. You need to remember to assign your input fields with IDs and then use GetElementById to do the calculations between the fields. Also I feel ONCHANGE works better than onkeyup.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b87s5hou/5/

**HTML**

```
<form action="postenquiry.php" method="post" name="myform">
<label>Num of People</label>    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" onchange="getPeople(this);"/><br/>
<label>Price</label>    <input type="text" name="cost" id="cost" onchange="calculate(this);"/><br/>
<input type="text" name="textbox5" id="textbox5"/>
```

**JS**

```
function getPeople(input){ 
 if (isNaN(input.value)){
 input.value = 0;
 }
}    
function calculate(input){ 
 if (isNaN(input.value)){
 input.value = 0;
 }
var price = input.value;
var people = document.getElementById("qty").value;
var calc = price * people;
document.getElementById('textbox5').value = calc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hai  cool this type of problem i also faced so..i develop a some peace of code which is 
used to calculate automatically using text fields .... in this code ..

```html
 <html>
<body>
<form oninput="x.value=parseFloat(a.value)*parseFloat(b.value)">
<input type="number" id="a" value="0">
<input type="number" id="b" value="50"readonly>
<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <html>
<body>
<form oninput="x.value=a.value-((parseFloat(a.value)*parseFloat(b.value))/100)">
<input type="number" id="a" value="0">
<input type="number" id="b" value="50">
<input name="x" for="a b" readonly>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```